# In gRPC, why does the client also implement server/service methods?

Tags: grpc

[gRPC's guide](https://grpc.io/docs/guides/concepts/) states the following:

> On the client side, the client has a local object known as stub (for some languages, the preferred term is client) **that implements the same methods as the service**.

Why does the client have to implement these methods? Why would they want to? It seems to me that in most cases, the client calls the service because it lacks the ability to complete a certain task itself. Therefore, if it implements the method itself, what is the point of calling the service?

I'm still in the process of learning about gRPC, so my understanding is still very limited. However I have yet to encounter a clear explanation for why it functions this way.

Comment: It is not an server implementation, but rather a client object that implements the service "interface" that handles communicating with the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gRPC` sits on top of the transport (OSI) layer and manages all things related to TCP sockets for the HTTP connection.

Among other things, it handles:

- connection set up (creates TCP sockets), connection destruction, reconnection:

  - for server, makes it `listen` on a port and `accept` client connections,
  - for clients, it calls `connect` on server
    ip/port .
- `send`/`recv` - reading/writing messages from/to sockets, streaming of messages etc.

If client wants to send a message, it needs to create a message, serialize it (using maybe protocol buffers), and then hand over to gRPC (invoke gRPC client side API or `stub` as in diagram) for socket `send()`. If client has registered a response callback with gRPC, then it will get notified about the response from the server.

So, in effect, the work in done by the server, client is just calling the client side API so that gRPC could send out a request to gRPC server.

Following image from `https://grpc.io/docs/guides/` shows the gRPC stubs in client and server -
[image: https://grpc.io/docs/guides/]

If you want to look into socket level code in gRPC source:
Server - [github](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/f3c48495d5413d4e98b0dfc237145e8e7ce35842/src/core/lib/iomgr/tcp_server_utils_posix_common.cc)
Client - [github](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/f3c48495d5413d4e98b0dfc237145e8e7ce35842/src/core/lib/iomgr/tcp_client_posix.cc)